# java regex $ metacharacter

Tags: java, regex, end-of-line

I am new to java regex.I saw this in [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html):

> $ The end of a line

But when I try this snippet:

```
String str = "firstline\r\nsecondline";
String regex = "$";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "*"));
```

I guess result will be:

```
firstline*
secondline*
```

But I see this result:

```
firstline
secondline*
```

It seems that it `$` only matches the end of a String. So why do the docs say it matches "The end of a line"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enable multiline mode, then `$` will match both, the end of a line and the end of the input:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

i.e.:

```
Pattern.compile("$",Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

You can also use the flag expression `(?m)`, i.e.:

```
Pattern.compile("(?m)$");
```

The oracle docs you cite are really quite imprecise here. The documentation of the pattern class (link above) is more precise and should be your reference for Java RegExs.

Answer (score 3):

$ means end of *input*, not end of *line*.

However, this is easily solved using the "multi line" flag; change your regex to add `(?m)` at the front:

```
String regex = "(?m)$";
```

The multi line flag makes caret ^ and dollar $ match start and end of *lines*

Comment: What's the difference between `$` and `\z`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `\A` and `\Z` match start and end of input regardless of flags. Without the multi line flag on, they are synonymous with caret and dollar.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitive for the end of your input. If you have newline literals in your input, the `$` will not match them.

If you want to match every newline, something like:

```
str.replaceAll("(\r\n|$)", "*$1");
```

might work.

Comment: Perhaps you want `"(\r?\n|$)"` btw +1